# How to find reason for hanging process (probably I/O related)

Tags: linux, nfs, io

on Ubuntu 14.04 when I open a file browser or an "Open File" Dialog, the application hangs for about 5 to 10 seconds.

I suspect this is due to some NFS requests. But how can I find out for sure?
Is there a way to show all file system accesses and their latency?

The home directory and many other directories are mounted from remote machines via NFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run strace on a fresh process and filter for long-running calls, as described @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795831/how-to-use-strace-to-only-show-calls-that-take-a-lot-of-time

Answer (score 1):

You can use *mountstat*  command to watch you nfs client statistics including latency. Or use nfsiostat.

In general, configure your file manager to avoit file preview generation for non local filesystems.